# Cplex optimization program returns results equal to zero

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, solver, stochastic

I am currently working on an optimization problem in which a lake has 150 units of water. I am paid 3$ for each unit of water sold, but I need to guarantee that 100 units of water will remain at the end of the month or pay 5$ for each unit below the threshold of 100. I know that rain will bring 125 units of water (later on I will add stochastic rain).

My model is as follows

```
!pip install cplex
!pip install docplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.environment import Environment
env = Environment()
env.print_information()

mdl = Model()

x = mdl.continuous_var(lb=None, ub=None, name=None )
y = mdl.continuous_var(lb=None, ub=None, name=None )



r1=mdl.add_constraint( 150-x+y+125 >= 100  )    
s = mdl.solve()

mdl.maximize(  3*x-5*y )
obj = mdl.objective_value



print(x.solution_value)
print(y.solution_value)

print("* best objective is: {:g}".format(obj))

mdl.export("modelo_determinista_bajo.lp")
```

where x is the amount of water sold and y is the amount of water below the 100 units mark.

The output of the model is zero for x, y and the benefit.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?
Best regards.

Comment: I might be naive, but it looks like you solve the model before you add your objective. Try adding the objective *before* you solve the model. Also, export the model immediately before you solve it so that you know that the model being solved is what you exported.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick Thanks, but that's not it. The syntax is correct. If I change the order of the rows I get an error

Comment: Quite happy that the syntax of each line is correct. What do you mean when you say change the order of the rows? What did you try? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: I mean that if I write `s = mdl.solve()` after `mdl.maximize(  3*x-5*y )` and `obj = mdl.objective_value` I get a syntax error.

Comment: That wouldn't work; but I think that shouldn't give a syntax error, rather a runtime error. I think you should be calling mdl.maximize(...) to add the objective to the model, then mdl.solve() to solve the model, and only after you have solved the model can you ask for the actual value of the objective. If you ask a model for its objective value before you solve it then that makes no sense as the model will not know what the objective value will be until after it has solved the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.environment import Environment
env = Environment()
env.print_information()

mdl = Model()

x = mdl.continuous_var(lb=None, ub=None, name=None )
y = mdl.continuous_var(lb=None, ub=None, name=None )



r1=mdl.add_constraint( 150-x+y+125 >= 100  )    

mdl.maximize(  3*x-5*y )


s = mdl.solve()

obj = mdl.objective_value

print(x.solution_value)
print(y.solution_value)

print("* best objective is: {:g}".format(obj))

mdl.export("modelo_determinista_bajo.lp")
```

gives

```
175.0
0
* best objective is: 525
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Alex's code:

- `Model.maximize()` (resp. minimize()) simply *sets* the objective and sense, but does not run solve(), therefore no (new) solution is computed.
- By default, the objective is 0, which is not as silly as it may seem: CPLEX
  will try to find a *feasible* solution. If it succeeds, the objective value equals (of course) 0.
- Calling `mdl.objective_value` before `mdl.solve()` will cause a runtime error: no solution is present, so the attribute is empty, and an exception is raised; this is likely what you have encountered.
  You should get actually  a `DOcplexException`:

  docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Model<docplex_model1> has not been solved yet